# Cassandra / Scylla marshaling error: read_simple_bytes - not enough bytes (requested 841888305, got 10)

Tags: node.js, cassandra, scylla

I have a table called domains, which has 2 columns, one column is a string called domain which is the primary key, and the second column is named ip_addresses and is a set of inet addresses.

The code:

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

const client = new cassandra.Client({
    localDataCenter: 'us-east',
    contactPoints: ['REDACTED'],
    keyspace: 'default_keyspace'
});

const readInterface = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('./domains'),
    output: null,
    console: false
});

readInterface.on('line', async (line) => {
    const splitLine = line.split(',')

    const domain = splitLine[0]
    splitLine.shift()

    const query = `INSERT INTO domains (domain, ip_addresses) VALUES(?, ?);`;
    const parsed = splitLine.map(e => `'${e}'`)
    const ips = `{${parsed.join(',')}}`
    console.log("IPS ", ips)
    console.log('DOMAIN', domain)
    client.execute(query, [ domain, ips ]).then((result) => console.log('User with email %s', result.rows[0])).catch(e => console.error(e))
});

console.log("DONE")
```

The values:
IPS: `{'172.217.15.110'}`
DOMAIN: `google.com`

The error says this:

```
ResponseError: marshaling error: read_simple_bytes - not enough bytes (requested 841888305, got 10) Backtrace:   0x326f94d
  0xea40d6
  0xea42a6
  0xea44f1
  0x17cba2e
  0x17d1644
  0x17d1a18
  0x14ea92e
  0x14ec4b6
  0x15cd85e
  0x15d2801
  0x15aa827
  0x15b1634
  0x15b30fc
  0x15b3f9f
  0x15b5d8b
  0x15b5dad
  0x15baa48
  0x2d7d4bc
  0x2dda680
  0x2dda88f
  0x2e0f705
  0x2d79e69
  0x2d7af1e
  0xd2ff96
  /opt/scylladb/libreloc/libc.so.6+0x271a2
  0xc5502d
```

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the driver wasn't able to correctly serialize a set of IP addresses. I'm no node.js expert, but I assume that the driver simply isn't able to infer the correct type from a `"{'172.217.15.110'}"` string and simply serializes it as a string.

Here's why I think the driver sent something that isn't actually a set of ip addresses: Scylla returned an error informing that the size of a buffer seems to be `841888305`. This number is represented in hex as `322E3231`, which in turn looks suspiciously like a part of an ASCII string... and it actually represents `"2.21"` in ASCII, which is a substring of the string representation of the IP address you were trying to send.

In CQL, most types are serialized in the form of `[4 bytes of length][data]`. Scylla definitely parsed part of your IP string as the length, which means that it expected a different data layout.

You should browse the documentation and look how to let the driver know that what you're actually trying to send is a set of IP addresses, which is a CQL type `set<inet>`. Here's how I managed to put correct data from node.js into Scylla, based on your code (I hardcoded the address for simplicity, but you should get the idea):

```js
readInterface.on('line', async (line) => {
    const splitLine = line.split(',')

    const domain = splitLine[0]
    splitLine.shift()

    const query = `INSERT INTO domains (domain, ip_addresses) VALUES(?, ?);`;
    const ips = [cassandra.types.InetAddress.fromString('127.0.0.1')]
    console.log("IPS ", ips)
    console.log('DOMAIN', domain)
    client.execute(query, [ domain, ips ]).then((result) => console.log('User with email %s', result.rows[0])).catch(e => console.error(e))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Scylla crashed. What version do you run and what's the log msg?
It's possible to get a stacktrace from this, you can follow the procedure on the wiki.
If you run an old version, just upgrade to a supported one and retest.

Comment: Not a crash :) Our deserializer simply prints the trace of each failed deserialization, but the node is still stable and working after that. I'll present my suspicion in its own answer